# Why does texture-sampling only work at (0,0,0)?

Tags: opengl, shaders, textures, directx, hlsl

I want to save the color of every point of one object in the `RWTexture3D`(UAV Resource) and transfer them to another object in its shader.

I made a test in the two shaders. Both in the fragment shader.

In first shader, I gave

```
RWTexture3D<float4> gUAVColor;  
gUAVColor[uint3(0,0,0)] = float4(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
```

In second shader:

```
Texture3D<float4> gVoxelList;  
float4 output = gVoxelList.SampleLevel(SVOFilter, uint3(0,0,0),0);
```

The result is correct, I got `red` as the result.

But when I change the code, the texture cant be sampled correctly.

In first shader, I gave

```
RWTexture3D<float4> gUAVColor; 
gUAVColor[uint3(1,0,0)] = float4(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
```

In second shader:

```
Texture3D<float4> gVoxelList; 
float4 output = gVoxelList.SampleLevel(SVOFilter, uint3(1,0,0),0);
```

I only changed the pos which save the red color from `uint(0,0,0) to uint(1,0,0)`, but what I got changed to `black`, which means it's uncorrect.

If I use `gVoxelList[uint(1,0,0)].xyz` ,it works.

I have no idea where the mistake will be.

Comment: I'm not familiar with HLSL, but if it's like GLSL, don't the sampling coordinates get multiplied by the texture size?

Comment: yes, you are right, same to directx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer, `gVoxelList[texcoord].xyz` this texcoord is the same as the texture size. If we have 512x512x512 size 3Dtexture,then the texcoord should be in [0,512] of every axis.  The same to function `texture.Load(texcoord)` .

However, `gVoxelList.SampleLevel(Filter, sample_texcoord,0)` in sample function, this sample_texcoord should be in [0,1] of every axis. If we have 512x512x512 size 3Dtexture, we should use `gVoxelList.SampleLevel(Filter, texelpos/512.0f ,0)`, `texelpos` is where each texel is.